# Selenium/TestNG DataProvider - How to structure Excel sheets in combination with Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pom.xml, dataprovider

**Background**

I am developing a new approach to automated testing using Selenium/TestNG/POM. So far, we have very promising results and automated large parts of our regression testing.

Now, we came to the step of expanding our test set by parametrizing them. We have end2end flows defined over multiple pages, where the pages are modeled into page objects. Most of these pages are forms, and in the end we get a resulting product/report that combines all the information.

**Now my problem statement**

We want to use Excel sheets so our business analysts can input the parameters and the expected values. But I am struggling to find a good way to structure the sheets. The *naive* approach would be to have a column for every parameter, and a line for every test case. A slightly better approach would probably be to use a different sheet for each page object, in a workbook, having a different workbook for each flow.

But my fear is that, by doing this, we are undoing all the good the POM brings us. If we need to change something (add a field in one of the screens for example), we need to regenerate all the excel sheets, or at least manually update each one. This is not that much better than having to update each scenario. In fact, we probably still have to edit all the scenario's (for example, if the new field is "name", add everywhere a "fillName('John')" step.

Is there a better way? Or is the manual work unavoidable? Or am I implementing POM incorrectly if I still need to adapt most scenarios everytime I need to add a field?

Comment: Not a choice for you, if not excel, you can try XML for handling data flexibly.

Comment: @GirishBellamkonda I understand XML may be more flexible in that I can add stuff programatically and non required stuff can be hidden/optional. But Excel is really the preference, since everybody knows Excel, but XML is more tricky for businessy people.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create yet another solution which use Excel as page object source you are bringing youself back to stone age. Use modern frameworks to handle Page Objects issues e.g. [JDI](https://github.com/epam/JDI) with elements typification or [Selenide](http://selenide.org/) wich provides more concise way.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. At first sight, Selenide and JDI like a wrapper on top of Selenium elements, that provide additional, commonly occuring functionalities (like checkboxes, images, ...), may check them out in the near future, though not priority. I don't see how they help in parametrizing the tests. Perhaps I should be clearer. Let's say I have a test with about 5 pages, wich have 5 fields to fill out each, and I want to test variations, where I get my input from Excel. How do these frameworks help me with that?

Comment: So... it was not clear from questions. Create page objects in code with described frameworks. Use any data source - from code, database, excel. TestNG can use them for data providing.

Comment: yeah, that's my idea indeed. I am looking how to structure the Excel files from optimal maintainability. Almost all tutorials are simple examples, with just a couple parameters. But I struggle to find good examples for dataproviders for page objects.

Comment: IMHO, I would prefer to use database like mongo and create data inputs as documents. It would be easy to get them and convert to ready-to-use objects.